# Simple calculation function not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code but I cannot get it to work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_calc(date, price, performance):
    test = pd.DataFrame(columns=('date'), index=('date'))
    test['date'] = date
    test['new_value'] = price * (1 + performance)
    return(test)

print(test_calc(1, 100, 0.05))
```

The problem seems to be:
`TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'date' was passed`

I don't need it to be a `DataFrame` by the way. I just chose it because I used it before. Everything else failed as well, e.g. `test = []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list` at `pd.DataFrame(columns=[], index=[])`

```
def test_calc(date, price, performance):
    test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'], index=['date'])
    test['date'] = date
    test['new_value'] = price * (1 + performance)
    return(test)
```